# A class name can be the same as a protocol name in Swift?

Tags: swift, class, protocols

A class name can be the same as a protocol name in Swift? I want to implement a protocol that has the same name as another class.

Comment: I'd say "Don't do that." Even if it's legal, it sounds like a great way to confuse yourself and anybody else who tries to consume the work you're doing.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#protocols-describing-what-is-should-read-as-nouns) can be some help when naming your protocol

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A class name can only be the same as a protocol name if they are in different modules, or if the class is nested inside another type. Even then, it will probably be confusing.